# The permutations of the components of the vectors in N-dimensional space are mutually perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, closed-form

Find the maximum numbers of component of vectors of a given $n$ dimensions such that they are **perpendicular** to each other.

The condition is that the component in each vector has to be a **permutation** of of the original one

> **The original vectors:$e_1=(x_1, x_2......x_n)$**
>
> **all the permutations:$e_2=(x_9, -x_2......x_n)$, $e_3=(-x_4, x_{12}......-x_n)$......**

For example, vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, $(-x_2,x_1,-x_4,x_3)$ and $(x_3,x_4,-x_1,-x_2)$ are mutually perpendicular when $n$=$4$

When $n$ is **odd**, all the vectors formed by the permutation of the component of the vector are impossible to be **mutually perpendicular**, but I don't know the **proof**.

When $n$ is even, there are definitely many **vectors** which formed by the **permutation** of the components of the **original vectors** are **mutually perpendicular**.What's the pattern of the perpendicular?

I tried myself and find that the **vectors** of different combinations of $+$ and $-$ signs are always **mutually perpendicular** when $n$ is **even**.But I can't prove it.

With enumeration, it's easy to find the pattern, but where is the **proof**.

Comment: This is slightly nit-picky, but I wouldn't call $(-x_2, x_1, -x_4, x_3)$ a permutation of $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$; it's a bit more complicated than that. You're letting the symmetry group of the 4-dimensional cube act on vectors, not just the symmetric group.

Comment: can you explain this more detailedly

Comment: what is symmetry group

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264276/maximum-of-orthogonal-vectors – come on, Mclalalala, you know better than to do this.